# FULLTEXT index on Liquibase/MariaDB or Mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb, liquibase

I'm using Liquibase to let my database schema evolve. I want to add a FULLTEXT index to my MariaDB or Mysql database.
As per [MariaDB website](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/full-text-index-overview/) you can either create a FULLTEXT index with `create table`, `alter table` or `create index`.
The Liquibase `createIndex` tag is missing the FULLTEXT attribute. Does anybody know how to do a work around?

Answer (score 6):

Discovered that with the [sql tag of Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) this can be done.

Just leaving question and answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

Using the modifySql tag allows u to create MySQL FULLTEXT INDICES:

```
<changeSet author="metadevj" id="1640675289806-34">
    <createIndex indexName="idx_product_comments" tableName="products">
        <column name="comments"/>
    </createIndex>
    <modifySql>
        <replace replace="INDEX" with="FULLTEXT INDEX"/>
    </modifySql>
</changeSet>
```